# Serialize large object to JSON String

Tags: json, angular, typescript, stringify

I’m working on an Angular 5 Project where get Data an ASP.NET Core Service as JSON. This work very good. But when I will send the Object back to the Server, JSON.stingify() returns only 10000 char. if the string gets bigger than the 10000 the sting will be reduced in the middle (e.g. if you have a string of 12000 char you will get the first 5000 chars 3 Dots and the last 5000 chars => [0-5000]...[7000-12000]). 
At the moment I have no clue where this Problem comes from! It is a Browser thing or is it ES6 thing or Typescript – I have now clue.
Does anyone know a way to remove this limitation?
Thank you for helping 
Michael

Comment: Is this an `Array` that you're sending?

Comment: Possibly chunk the data by destructing the json in a logical way and then calling stringify on the smaller chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing the large JS Object has a memory constraint in all browsers. You can try JSONStream Node Modules. https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream. This might be helpfull.

Comment: it uses `require' for node How can it be used in angular.THanks in advance